# AWS target groups to IPs of a VPC endpoint. Can it be done?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, vpc-endpoint

So I want to front a VPC endpoint in AWS with an ALB. I'm manually creating target groups for the IPs of the VPCE. The problem I'm having is that they are always red because I can't setup request headers for the VPC endpoint, which points to my API gateway.

Has anyone else setup static IPs of a VPC endpoint in a target group before? I even tried to make the healthy status as a 403 response but no go